DC voltage comparison
I have three conditions to indicate the device status,

If the measured voltage is <7V, then the device is short.
If the measured voltage is >7V and <15V, then device is OK
If the measured voltage is >15V, then the device is open

I came across IC called LM393, as far as I understood from datasheet, the supply voltage can be 2-36V DC. My application requires 24V DC, in this case should I have to design three circuit with three LM393 and reference voltage conditions?? can any one explain how to perform this in practical

I've rolled the question back to how it was when I originally answered it. Please don't evolve questions once an answer is given without careful thought as to the impact on already given answers. This isn't a forum; you ask a question and you get answers in return. If you modify your question you may easily invalidate answers already given so don't do this. Instead raise a brand new post. I mean this is a Q and A site so raising a brand new post is this site's bread and butter.

The conditions "open", "closed" can be interpreted in different ways, making your question somewhat ambiguous. I'm going to assume you mean "on" or "off", in the same way an LED can be on or off, which is not the same as a "high" or low potential (voltage).
The good news is that it's easy to produce a "high" or "low" potential, and use that to switch something else (like an LED, or a motor) on or off. That's a different problem though, which I won't address here. More good news is that the LM393 is exactly the right tool for the job of comparing voltages, and I'll show you how in a moment.
The bad news is that you don't just have two conditions; there's a third "OK" condition, meaning that you can no longer represent state using a single binary "high" or "low" potential signal. You will need at least two signals, one of which I will call "OK", the other will come later.
In essence, to derive an "OK" signal, your solution needs to make two voltage comparisons simultaneously, one to determine if the signal exceeds +15V, and another to determine if that same signal is less than +7V. You must then combine those two results using some logical operation such as "OR" or "AND" or "NOR" (we'll determine with later), to provide an "OK" signal. The name given to such a system is "window compoarator", and requires two comparators, both of which can be found in a single LM393 package.
The sources of +7V and +15V can be derived using a simple resistor potential divider, consisting of R1, R2 and R3 here:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The outputs OVER' and UNDER' have apostrophes in their names to indicate that they are "active low". The will have low potential when the condition is met. OVER' will go to low potential when \$V_{IN}>+15V\$, and UNDER' will be low when \$V_{IN}<+7V\$ See this in action as \$V_{IN}\$ (blue) rises and falls between 0V and +24V:

Both are high only when \$V_{IN}\$ lies between those two thresholds.
Since the LM393 has open-collector outputs (which you can read about in this answer), it is possible to physically join them, and obtain a single "OK" signal, which is high only when both comparators produce high outputs:

simulate this circuit

However, you lose the independent OVER' and UNDER' signals. You can preserve them if you employ a "diode-AND" arrangement, which side-steps the need to join the comparator outputs:

simulate this circuit
The last step would be to build hardware to respsond to these signals, and "open" or "close" things, switch thing on or off.
Some final notes: You can't use an LMV393 (with the "V"), since that doesn't work with more than 5.5V supply. Secondly, the LM393 can only sink current to ground into its output, meaning that its output "load" (such as a resistor and/or LED) must be connected between comparator output and the positive supply rail. You cannot directly power an LED or any other load connected between output and ground.

Thank you simon. I have ordered components to test the above circuit and will come back if I have any doubts during testing


should I have to design three circuit with three LM393 and reference
voltage conditions

You only need two comparators: -

One to detect the below 7 volts condition and,
One to detect the above 15 volts condition

Then you use logic gates to resolve the three output states.

can any one explain how to perform this in practical

What more info do you need (I'm presuming you meant in practice)?

The schematic shown is related to this question, i drafted the circuit but i need  someone to check whether this circuit  will work for my requirement

I advised you to raise a new post rather than post questions in answers. You did this on a previous question you asked and the moderator did inform you about this.

@priya - Hi, (a) You shouldn't change a question after receiving answers to it to ask "someone" to review a proposed solution. That makes existing answers look incomplete since they won't have addressed changes to the question (and there is no requirement for answers to "chase" an evolving question). (b) As commented above, again you posted a "non-answer" which was a question asking for a schematic review. That will be deleted. That is "forum-type" behaviour, but it doesn't fit the Q&A format of Stack Exchange. Only answers (not questions) should be posted in the "Your Answer" box below.

(continued) (1) If you need to clarify whether you have understood an answer correctly, you can ask in a comment below that answer. You can include an image link in a comment, as I explained when you did this before. (2) However, at some point, a request for schematic review exceeds being a clarification comment and should be a whole new question. Listen to the guidance of other site members or ask for guidance on our [meta].

@priya if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
